# How to select an image in a cell with no id/class by css/javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to select an image inside a table cell to add some addition style. The HTML code is generated by sharepoint so there is no id/class directly at the picture and I can't edit it. I have no idea how can I select it by css or javascript.

The next class above the picture I want to select:

```
<td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" style="width:25%;">​
  <a href="/cs/supplyhub/Plants/Forms/AllItems.aspx">
    <img src="/cs/supplyhub/SiteAssets/Picture21.png" 
         alt="Picture21.png" style="margin:5px;width:200px;height:133px;">
  </a>
  <br>
</td>
```

I read quite a lot of topic about selector, but I failed to implement them to my situation so pls lend me a hand. The goal is to add some mouseover effect to represent the picture is working as a button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **querySelector** to get the first element that matches, keep in mind that if there are more `<td>` elements with the same class, you may not select the exact image you are looking for:

```
document.querySelector('.ms-rteTableEvenCol-0 > a > img');
```

If you know the  src attribute you can also do:

```
document.querySelector('img[src="/cs/supplyhub/SiteAssets/Picture21.png"]');
```

Or by alt text:

```
document.querySelector('img[alt="Picture21.png"]');
```

The **CSS selectors** are exactly the same as the strings given to `querySelector`:

```
.ms-rteTableEvenCol-0 > a > img { ... }

img[src="/cs/supplyhub/SiteAssets/Picture21.png"] { ... }

img[alt="Picture21.png"] { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

With CSS you can do:

```
td.ms-rteTableEvenCol-0 > a > img {
    /* rules here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
$("td.ms-rteTableEvenCol-0 a img")
```

This will select every `img` that is inside a `a` that is inside a `td` with the class `ms-rteTableEvenCol-0`.

Comment: Question wasn't tagged with JQuery.